# Weird readings with i2C communication with MCP9880

Tags: i2c

this will be my first time asking a question. First of all, I am just a programmer, I don't know much about electronics.

I am trying to communicate with a MCP9880 temeprature sensor through i2c, but I am getting weird readings in between 'real' ones, output looks like this (in decimal):

```
0 29
255 255
128 0
0 29
255 255
255 255
```

Here the 'real' lecture would be 128 0, but normally I get either 0xff or 0x1D as you can see. This happens reading any register. Also, other i2c devices are working as expected, but the many MCP9808 that we tried keep the same behaviour. Here's the code I use to read the temperature register (in bascom, I'm forced to use it :( )

```
I2cstart                         'StartI2C.
I2cwbyte Wr_sensor1              'MCP9808 addr.
I2cwbyte &H05                    'Temperature register

I2cstart                         'StartsI2C.
I2cwbyte Rd_sensor1              'MCP9808 addr
I2crbyte Temp_1621 , Ack         'Read first byte
I2crbyte Temp_1621_dec , Nack    'Read second byte
I2cstop
```

The addresses are checked and correct, and I really think the code should be right. I keep saying this is an electronics issue, but keep saying they checked and everything is allright.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Here's a link to the datasheet http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/25095A.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. Doing further tests, the device acted as if it resetted itself all the time. I suspected tiny voltage drops, so I researched the topic, plugged a capacitor, and that was it!

I hope this can help somebody :)

Comment: Man! After weeks of changing my code, I found this post. I think I'm having the same problem. Would you tell me more about your setup and solution? Thanks so much.

Comment: Sorry Man, my email address was blown and I just recovered this account. I assume you don't need a response anymore, but I will try to clarify just in case for somebody else. I don't remember the setup at the time, and my knowledge of electronics is very very basic, But the problem was that the chip was very sensitive to voltage drops, so adding a capacitor before it to stabilize the voltage made the trick. Just be sure the chip has a stable input all the time.

Comment: Thanks, Hector. You've got great memory .)) IIRC, my problem was solved by disabling overclocking on the Raspberry Pi I was running the code on. It somehow interfered with the I2C (again - IIRC) and switching that off eventually helped. Was one of the longest bugs I ever had to solve. Cheers!